# Изображения для категорий все одинаковые, почему?

Tags: php, wordpress, изображения

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Нужно на главной странице вывести категории статей в виде картинок. Нашел решение по этой [ссылке](https://wp-kama.ru/id_7686/miniatyury-dlya-elemetov-taksonomij.html). Одна проблема, на всех категориях отображается только ода картинка, а не разные. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема?

Вот код вывода категорий:

```
    <section class="container pt-3">
  <div class="row mt-5 mb-5 text-light">    
    <?php
      $categories = get_categories(array(
           orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'type' => 'post'
      );
      foreach( $categories as $category ){
      ?>
      <div class="work col-3 mt-1 pr-1 item">
        <div class="copywriter">
          ?php
          echo '<a class="rounded border border-light p-2" href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a>';
$term_id = get_queried_object_id();
// получим ID картинки из метаполя термина
$image_id = get_term_meta( $term_id, '_thumbnail_id', 1 );
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, 'full' );
// выводим картинку на экран
echo '<img src="'. $image_url .'" alt="" />';
?>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Потому что `get_queried_object_id()` предназначен для работы в главном цикле WordPress. У вас он всегда возвращает одно и то же.

Comment: Нужно вывести его из цикла?

Comment: KAGG Design, Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach( $categories as $category ){
    $image_id = get_term_meta( $category->term_id, '_thumbnail_id', 1 );
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, 'full' );
}
```

Comment: Krya, Большое спасибо.